# Очистка формы с помощью js.

Tags: javascript, html, html-form

После отправки формы, она заполняется данными, которые ввел пользователь.
Из-за того, что страница обновляется с уже готовыми данными, форма по кнопке не очищается.
Как реализовать очищение формы?

```
function  clearForm() {
    $("#name").val("");
    $("#pics").val("");
    $("#names").val("");
}
```

Не помогает.

**Обновление**

Я вешаю функцию на событие onclick при нажатии на кнопку очистки.

```
$('form input[type="text"], form input[type="password"], form textarea').val('');
```

не срабатывает так же. Я не хочу чистить форму автоматически, мне нужно, чтобы это делал пользователь.

Comment: Где вы используете функцию clearForm? 
По идее, её нужно впихнуть как success-функцию POST-запроса например.

Comment: @AccessDenied, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Ни один из ответов не верен. Форма не очищается после обновлении страницы и заполнении ее данными с помощью php.

Comment: @AccessDenied, приложите код формы со скриптом очистки. Может, неправильно что-то делаете.

Comment: Нечего, все банально просто, обычная кнопка ресет, на которой висит онклик, который вызывает функцию очистки формы яваскриптом. В форме в value в инпутах стоят предыдущие значения, их нужно очищать по нажатию на кнопку, но стандартный ресет не работает, в принципе как и скриптовый.

Comment: @AccessDenied, может быть, так? http://jsfiddle.net/vqky0qc8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('form input[type="text"], form input[type="password"], form textarea').val('');
```

Answer (score 7):

В `jQuery`:

```
    $('form[name=myForm]').trigger('reset');
```

На чистом `javascript`:

```
    document.myForm.reset();
```

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста, незакрытую кавычку в своем сообщении

Comment: VenZell, спасибо за ваши замечания, но где вы видите незакрытую кавычку?

Comment: Вам ее исправили в 12:30 в день моего обращения. Т.е. после моего комментария. Посмотрите историю правок своего сообщения.

Comment: Да, вижу! Благодарю за расъяснения!

Comment: Работает, хороший пример, и радио и чекбоксы чистит.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml - вот хорошая статья по теме с примерами, и RubaXa с user210195 правильно посоветовали.

```
<form name="data_entry" action="#">

Company Name: <input type="text" size="35" name="company_name"><br>

Select Business Type: <input type="radio" name="business_category" value="1"> Manufacturer
<input type="radio" name="business_category" value="2"> Whole Sale Supplier
<input type="radio" name="business_category" value="3"> Retailer
<input type="radio" name="business_category" value="4"> Service Provider

Email Address: <input type="text" size="30" name="email"><br>

Keep Information Private: <input type="checkbox" name="privacy"><br>

<input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Reset Form" onclick="this.form.reset();">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6g48kfpe/ - этот работающий пример.

http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/javascript-clear-form/javascript-reset-form-example.html - оно же, но с дополнительной функцией, сбрасывающей все значения (даже те, у которых что-то стоит по умолчанию).

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('myForm').reset()`, не?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".any-button").click(function() {

    $("form")[0].reset();

});
```