# Как очистить форму при AJAX запросе

Tags: jquery, laravel

Всем привет я новичок в Laravel и AJAX подскажите как очистить форму после AJAX запроса?

```html
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header"><h5>Сообщение</h5></div>
     <div class="card-body">

      <div class="float-right">
       <a class="btn btn-danger" href="home" role="button">Вернуться</a>
      </div>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/JavaScript">

       $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#contact").submit(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
          url: "{{route('contact')}}", 
          beforeSend: function() {
           $("#load").fadeIn(400);
           }, 
          type: "post", 
          data: $("#contact").serialize(), 
          success: function(answer) {
           $("#answer").html(answer);
          }
         }).done(function() {
          $("#load").fadeOut(400);
         });
        });
       });
      
      </script>
      <form id="contact" action="" name="contact" method="post">
       @csrf
       <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><br/>
       <button class="btn btn-success" name="send">отправить</button>
       <input type="hidden" name="name" value={{$_POST['name']}}>
       <input type="hidden" name="auth_email" value={{$_POST['auth_email']}}>
       <input type="hidden" name="user_email" value={{$_POST['user_email']}}>
      </form>
      <div id="answer"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `$("#yourFormId").trigger('reset');`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Очистка формы с помощью js.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/382620/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-js)