# как убрать значение после сабмита

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста как решить следующую проблему:

Есть форма которая появляется с помощью попапа, в ней есть два инпута, после ввода данных создается карточка с данными без перезагрузки страницы. Как сделать чтобы при повторном клике на кнопку вызова попапа поля формы очистились от предыдущих введеных значений?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/382620/508294

Comment: Покажите ваш код и что именно не получается?